# Что означает строчка Text.VuPoint.login_username_lbl?

Tags: asp.net

Помогите, плиз. Нужно перевести сайт на русский язык, все названия ссылаются на фрейм. Подскажите, что означает эта строчка `<%=Text.VuPoint.login_username_lbl%>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что за объекты Text и VuPoint используются в данной строке? В данной строке идет обращение к каким-то объектам системы (только вы можете посмотреть, что это за объекты, имея исходники) и в результирующий html выводится значение св-ва login_username_lbl выше упомянутых объектов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, все названия ссылаются на <%text.vupoint ...username, password, search,portal и тд%> Мне как раз нужно поменять названия(username, password, search, portal и тд)поиск по всем файлам исходников по login_username_lbl, находит только в dll файле. Возможно ли что в dll корректируются названия? P.S dll файлы нормально не отображаются

Comment: К сожалению за вас я не смогу найти место, где сетится данный текст. Возможно ета инфа хранится в ресурсных файлах, а возможно и в отдельной ДЛЛ, причем если у вас нет ее исходников, то приидется ее переписать. Чтобы посмотреть код ДЛЛ используйте какой-либо рефлектор, например IL Spy

Comment: Если проект не секретный для вас, можете прислать его мне и я вам скажу где хранятся строки, хотя такого подхода данный форум и не поощряет, но я просто уверен, что это быстро выясняется.

Comment: ok, было бы здорово, не могли дать ваш емаил?

Comment: Отправил вам на почту

Comment: Нужные вам тексты действительно хранятся в ДЛЛ под именем "Micros" в пространстве имен "Micros.Text". Там лежит адский класс "VuPointText" в котором хранится КУЧА строк. При его распознавании рефлектор у меня чуть не лег =)

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте создал ресурсные файлы, в которые положил бы все необходимые вам строки. Ну и обращения к строкам на всех страницах придется поменять.

Comment: Ааааа, стоп! Предыдущие разработчики все таки постарались это сделать хоть как то настраиваемым... В классе Text строки, глядя на код, вроде как должны подгружаться из файла, указанного там. Посмотрите код етой длл и поищите подобный файл и тд - возможно вы обойдетесь только изменением файла со строками. Хотя в классе все строки жестко заданы. В общем бардак тут.

Comment: Спасибо большое за содействие, у Вас открылась dll-ла через IL Spy
?

Comment: Да - открылась.Она разработана вот так: // Architecture: AnyCPU
// Runtime: .NET 1.1

Comment: ILSpy version 1.0.0.1000

Comment: До этого открывал Resourse Hacker не открылась, через Il Spy открылась, еще раз спасибо большое буду искать в dll-ке.

Comment: Здесь (спасибо == пометить ответ правильным) :)